# Why does running a callback from useEffect print the wrong value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to understand this weird behavior:

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCounter(2);

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('counter = ', counter); // => counter = 1
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your effect will be called when your component is first mounted, cause you're passing empty array of deps ... where your `counter` variable is `1`

`setCounter` function is an `async` function, `react-native ui` will push that call into the stack of function-calls that's supposed to be called in order, but the the first function call pushed into that stack of calls is your `console.log`, with a copy of the value of `counter` variable which is `1`

If you want to print the updated value of `counter`, put `counter` to the list of `deps` like:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(1);
useEffect(() => {
  setCounter(2);
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('counter = ', counter); // => counter = 1
  }, 1000);
}, [counter]);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is worth mentioning, you are using counter state value inside useEffect. This is targeted by ESLint with default settings. Your useEffect depends on that state and it should be added to dependency array.[ESLint error][1]

This correct usage of useEffect would cause useTimeout to run 2 times. On initial render and after rerender.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiLJi.png